# jQuery hiding content based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi all i am trying to hide content for a ppc campaign, so if they come from the link they will have something like "/?utm_source=google" on the url

Ive got the following but it only works for that exact url

```
 var url = "http://mysite.com/?utm_source=google";
  if (location.href==url){
    $('div').hide();
  }
```

Ideally it needs to work for multiple pages i.e. http://mysite.com/page-one/?utm_source=google

Just wondering if anyone knows a way around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method like String.contains() in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript) - this is essentially what OP is asking.

Comment: Why don't you use getting the Query String? That will always provide you the query string name and its value too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a regexp match:

```
  if (location.href.match(/utm\_source\=google/ig)){
    $('div').hide();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var option = 'coke';
    var url = window.location.href;
    option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
    showDiv(option);
});
function showDiv(option) {
    $('.boxes').hide();
    $('#' + option).show();
}
```

[Read the Contents](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/10/09/how-to-hide-or-show-content-based-on-links-or-urls-via-javascript-jquery/)